# Plot aligned barplots in the same graph

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to use the R barplot function to plot the following array on the same graph:

```
ID  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
HeL 0   2   1   4   2   3   2   4
CaC 2   0   0   2   1   5   7   8
NIH 1   2   5   6   3   5   7   9
```

I would need to have the barplot of each row having its own y-axis, but the x-axis should be common for all rows. What I have achieved so far, is to read the matrix  from the file "rna.tab" and then plot each row separately:

```
dat <- read.table ("rna.tab", row.names=1, header=TRUE)
barplot (as.matrix (dat[,1]))
barplot (as.matrix (dat[,2]))
barplot (as.matrix (dat[,3]))
```

but I didn't succeed in plotting them all together. 
Thanks in advance-
Arturo

Comment: `library(tidyverse) ; df %>% rownames_to_column('ID') %>% gather(var, val, -ID) %>% ggplot(aes(var, val, fill = ID)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?  If it isn't could you please make a manual example of what you want and post the image?

```
par(mfrow = c(ncol(dat),1), mar = c(2.5,4,1,1))
apply(dat, 2, barplot, beside = TRUE)
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

The first `par` say you want a grid of plots with as many rows as there are columns of `dat` and 1 column, and changes the margins of the plot to be appropriate.  The apply function makes a barplot for eash column of `dat` and `beside = TRUE` puts the columns next to each other.  The next `par` resets the plotting grid to a single graph so next time you need to plot something you aren't just making a bunch of tiny plots.

Comment: Thank you. But when I type the first line, I get an error: par(mfrow = c((ncol(dat),1), mar = c(2.5,4,1,1))  Error: unexpected ',' in "par(mfrow = c((ncol(dat),"

Comment: sorry, stray parentheses, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Barker for the fix and sorry for taking so long to get back to you, but I was sick for almost one week.
Your code works great, the only thing is that, since I need to plot the rows and not the columns, it should be: 
    apply(dat, 1, barplot, beside = TRUE)
Sorry for not being clear about this point.

I have just one last question, if you don't mind. Usually my real life matrix is 6000*30. This means that I have to plot 30 rows.
Usually I save the image to disk:

```
png ("plot.png")
par(mfrow = c(ncol(dat),1), mar = c(2.5,4,1,1))
apply(dat, 1, barplot, beside = TRUE)
dev.off ()
```

When I do this, I get only the plot of the last 4 rows in the file "plot.png", instead of the plot of all rows. Also, since the x-axis is the same for all plots, would be possible to draw it only at the end?